# Java2D Array rows

Tags: java

I would like to know if it is possible to get max length of a row in java 2D array

for example:

my Array : {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3}};

So I have array that has 3 columns (I can get it with Array.length) and max lenght of a row is 5. How would I get this number

Comment: Please have a look at the basic java documentation.

Comment: Duplicate??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665461/finding-maximum-elements-of-columns-in-java-2d-array-of-variable-row-length

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through all the rows to find the maximum length:

```
int max = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].length > max) {
        max = myArray[i].length;
    }
}
return max;
```